# how to apply Regular Expression on Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need a Textbox that must take a value like this

1. character: first it will take from user only Integer.if not integer it will not display it.that is only integer.
2. character: if integer is entered than it will  append automatically  "/".
3. character: after this "only characters must be enter" and not integer.if not character it will not enter the integer.
4. character: if characters is entered than it will append automatically   "/".
5. character: after this it will append constant "uet" automatically  .
6. character: after constant = uet is enterd it will append automatically   "/" and automatically   current year.

For example, the value of textbox must be

```
5 integer/5 characters/uet/2012

Length of Character = 5

Length of Integer   = 5
put "/" if integer length = 5
put "/" if charcter length = 5
```

Comment: Why don't you use multiple inputs? Show them one by one once the filled one is correct.

Comment: no its requirement that it must be one textbox and not multiple inputs element

Comment: provide multiple boxes and send these inputs to one text box with the requirements you want.............

Comment: @ankur20us i need one textbox to do so.

Comment: I don't understand #1 and #3 are characters allowed or not???

Comment: @powtac #1 = only integer must be enter not character. #3=only charcter must be enter and not integer

Comment: @EdwardMaya in the same textbox??? This can not be. Or does the numbers show the positions of the chars in the textbox?

Comment: @powtac yes sir! in the same textbox and NOT muliple input elements

Comment: @powtac sir ! i am editing the question and putting the format

Comment: Good idea and add an example...

Comment: The headline should not be about regexp since there has to be also string manipulations...

Comment: how long the any integer

Comment: @khaled_webdev length of character and integer = 5

Comment: cause how it will be append automatically "/" and we don't know when integer will finish

Comment: im currently developing it, but i have a question
part 3: if user enters a integer and not a string, you want the (integer)/ to be removed?

Comment: maybe there is a mask technique hwo will helping you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just catch `keypress` event and allow characters based on length.
See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/wLqj7/

This is a simple example just for notice and doesn't work with copy-paste and some other cases.

Additionally you may want to take a look at [jquery masked-input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)
But if this is the only case where you need some text filtering, I guess it'll be better to write your own rule

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]*)/([a-z]*)/uet/[0-2][0-2][0-9][0-9]$
```

This is a regex that matches:

123/qwerty/uet/2012

12drfsdf3/qwerty/uet/2012 doesn't match.

It can probably be shorter, but thats what I could come up with now.